# Running Expresse middleware in parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

How can I run my middleware in parallel, when a certain middleware takes parameters? I was reading [this article](https://engineering.gosquared.com/making-dashboard-faster), where they have calls like the following:

```
app.use(getUser);
```

But I have calls like the following:

```
app.use(require('./middleware/settings')(config));
```

Also when is it best to use this approach, as I have many middlewares being initialised and fired in my app.js, such as the following:

```
app.use(require("connect-assets")({
  paths:    [config.app.assets_dir + '/css',
             config.app.assets_dir + '/js',
             config.app.assets_dir + '/images',
             config.app.assets_dir + '/fonts',
             config.app.assets_dir + '/bower_components'
            ],
  buildDir: config.app.min_dir,
  gzip:     true
}));
```

Should I use it for some or all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique in the article you linked to doesn't really apply to your situation directly. They are talking about a single request that requires multiple independent bits of I/O and refactoring from a serial process to a parallel process. For an asset pipeline, the situation is different and that technique doesn't apply directly. Plus with a third party module you don't have control over any IO connect-assets is doing while building your assets, but it all only happens once anyway. Just consider using their `precompile` option and you'll be OK.

For common third party middleware like assets managers, static servers, etc, things are already "parallel" in that the express server can respond to many requests at once. The async.parallel technique is better suited when your custom business logic has IO tasks that do not require serial execution.